# How to add Blob AND Table to the same Azure Store

Tags: azure, blob

For some time now I have successfully used Azure Blobs. Now I would like to add a Table to the same Azure Store, but that won't work. I get no error in return.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
        Dim MyBlobClient As CloudBlobClient = MyStoreAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient
        Dim MyContainer As CloudBlobContainer = MyBlobClient.GetContainerReference("demoblob")
        MyContainer.CreateIfNotExists()

        Dim MyTableClient As CloudTableClient = MyStoreAccount.CreateCloudTableClient
        Dim MyTable As CloudTable = MyTableClient.GetTableReference("demotable")
        MyTable.CreateIfNotExists()
```

Of course I have resolved the connectionstring first, that's not the issue. As a result of the above code, a container with the name "demoblob" is created. But a table with the name "demotable" isn't. The code is contained within a Try/Catch/EndTry and no error is thrown.

What goes wrong? Is it at all possible to mix blobs and tables in the same store?

Comment: How are you checking if or not the table is created? Your code looks fine to me.

Comment: Hi Gaurav,Thanks for getting back to me. I check this by logging on into the Azure Management Portal and look for the name of the table. I presume it would appear in the list under the Store name, just like the names of the blob containers that reside there. Is that (not) the right way to check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table storage is another type of storage (apart from blob storage) provided by Windows Azure. While blobs allow you to store unstructured data in Windows Azure, tables allow you to store structured data in there. Table storage is the NoSql data store.

At this time, you can't browse tables in your storage account through Windows Azure portal. To see the tables in your storage account, you would need to use another tool which supports table storage.

If you're using Visual Studio, you can view tables through Server Explorer. To view tables through server explorer, add your storage account connection by right clicking on `Windows Azure Storage` node and then clicking on `Add New Storage Account` and then add storage credentials manually. There're 3rd party tools (both free and paid) which can also be used to view the tables. You can find the list of storage explorers here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/04/17/windows-azure-storage-explorers.aspx.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav!You were right in your first reaction (as was my code). The problem was not that the table was not created, but it is not visible (that's odd indeed...!) in Azure Management Portal. With you suggestion to connect it via Server Explorer I can see the table was created, and it contains all of my attempts as well.